# Redirection causes "Object reference not set to an instance of an Object" error

Tags: acumatica

I have Created a Button on the Business Accounts (CR303000) Contracts tab called "Create Contract" (Screenshot 1). The button is supposed to redirect to the Customer Contracts (CT301000) and the Customer field needs to be populated with the current Business Account(screenshot 2). When I click the button I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" (screenshot 3).

**Screenshot 1:**
[image]

**Screenshot 2:**

[image]

**Screenshot 3:**

[image]

Code Snippet

```
public PXAction<PX.Objects.CR.BAccount> CreateContract;
  
    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Create Contract")]
    protected void createContract()
    {
            ContractMaint contractMaint = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ContractMaint>();

            Contract newContract = new Contract();
            

                     
            newContract.CustomerID = Base.BAccount.Current.BAccountID;

            contractMaint.Contracts.Update(newContract);


            throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(contractMaint, true, "New Contract")
            {
                Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow
            };


    }
```

How can I redirect to Customer Contract and have the Customer field populated?

Answer (score 0):

```
public PXAction<PX.Objects.CR.BAccount> CreateContract;
  
    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Create Contract")]
    protected void createContract()
    {
            ContractMaint contractMaint = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ContractMaint>();

            //Contract newContract = new Contract();
           // newContract.CustomerID = Base.BAccount.Current.BAccountID;
           // contractMaint.Contracts.Update(newContract); <== // You've called the Update method for record that haven't been inserted.

 //First you can find the existing record from a view and put it in Current of view like that:

contractMaint.Contracts.Current = contractMaint.Contracts.Search<Contract.CustomerID>(Base.BAccount.Current.BAccountID);

if(contractMaint.Contracts.Current is Contract) <==// Be sure that the record was found and the current isn't null.

            throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(contractMaint, true, "New Contract")
            {
                Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow
            };
    }
```